# Batch file with quotes for network directy and wildcard

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I'm trying to get a script to rename a PDF file inside of a networked drive. The folder will have a lot of .txt files, but just one .pdf, which will be randomly named. Basically, I need to rename the random part to say FILE_yyyyddmm.pdf However, I'm not sure how to use a wildcard inside of the quotes in my network drive. Note that I cannot mount this area as a network drive.

```
:: Get current date
for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('date /T') do set CDATE=%%B
for /F "tokens=1,2 eol=/ delims=/ " %%A in ('date /T') do set mm=%%B
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/ eol=/" %%A in ('echo %CDATE%') do set dd=%%B
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ('echo %CDATE%') do set yyyy=%%B
set date=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
::Rename PDF and move to new folder
move "\\network-drive\Folder1\Folder2\*.pdf" "\\network-drive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\%date%.pdf"
```

Using `copy` instead of `move` does create a PDF named correctly, but it's a 1kb file that cannot be opened, so it doesn't appear to be copying the *.PDF filename

Knowing that I need to name the drives inside of quotes, how can I also get it to do a wildcard on the PDF? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mofi. I'm not worried about the date part. After some tweaking it is working now.

`:: Get current date
    for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('date /T') do set CDATE=%%B
    for /F "tokens=1,2 eol=/ delims=/ " %%A in ('date /T') do set mm=%%B
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/ eol=/" %%A in ('echo %CDATE%') do set dd=%%B
    for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ('echo %CDATE%') do set yyyy=%%B
    set date=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
    ::Rename PDF and move to new folder
    move "\\network-drive\Folder1\Folder2\*.pdf" "\\network-drive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\NEW_NAME_%date%.pdf"

PAUSE`

Comment: Sorry Mofi, I didn't mean you weren't being helpful! I don't do this enough and hit enter before typing out all of what I had. I'm not 100% why it works now but didn't originally.Thanks for the /? command, I'm more used to Linux commands than Windows

Comment: Sort of not going to do it at this point. Super new-user friendly aren't you, eh?